# what is the limit of $(\log n)/n^{(1/100)}$ as n approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am kind of confused about this question, are we allowed to take l'Hopitals rule, can someone please show me the steps.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) or at the very least parentheses when you write mathematical expressions. I genuinely can't tell whether you mean $\log\left(\frac n{n^{1/100}}\right)$ or $\frac{\log n}{n^{1/100}}$.

Comment: Hint for intuition: look at what happens if you double $n$, that is, swap out $n$ for $2n$ in your expression (this is difficult to make into a rigorous proof, but will hopefully give you a good idea of what's going on)

Comment: This might be a technicality, and slightly pedntic, and me making an assumption from your notation that you haven't specified at all, but if $n$ is assumed to be an integer as opposed to a real number then you aren't actually allowed to do l'Hopital, simply because derivatives with respect to $n$ are meaningless. You can claim that the derivative of $\ln(n)$ is $1/n$, but you have to work really hard to make that mean anything in the absence of a continuum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is 0.**

*Yes, you can use  l'Hopitals rule, to find the limit of this function. Since numerator and Denominator each is limiting to infinity at infinity.*

- Derivative( log(n) ) = 1/n
- Derivative( n<sup>1/100</sup> ) = 1/100 * n <sup>- 99/100</sup>

So as per l'Hopitals rule : lim<sub>n->inf</sub> [ ( log(n) ) / ( n<sup>1/100</sup> ) ] = lim<sub>n->inf</sub> [ 100 / ( n<sup>1/100</sup> ) ] = 0.

Moreover, *functions of the form **x<sup>a</sup>** always grow faster than **logarithmic functions***. **Therefore, you can safely assume as limit turning out out be 0.**

Comment: Can you please mark it as correct ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to take a extra logarythm :
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} {{\log n} \over {n^{1 \over 100}}}
 = \lim_{n\to\infty} {e^{\log { {log n} \over {n^{1 \over 100}}}}} =
 \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{({ \log\log n - {1 \over 100} \log n})} = \lim_{x\to\infty} { e^{-x}} = 0
$$
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

For sure, you can use L'Hospital rule.

Using algebra, consider the function $$f(n)=\frac{\log (n)}{n^{\frac 1 {100}}}$$ $$f'(n)=\frac{1}{n^{101/100}}-\frac{\log (n)}{100 n^{101/100}}$$ $$f''(n)=\frac{101 \log (n)}{10000 n^{201/100}}-\frac{51}{50 n^{201/100}}$$ The first derivative cancels if $n=e^{100}$ and $$f(e^{100})=\frac{100}{e}\qquad \text{and}\qquad f''(e^{100})=-\frac{1}{100 e^{201}}<0$$ So, the point  $n=e^{100}$ corresponds to a maximum and from there the function decreases in a monotonic manner to $0$.

If you set $n=e^{10^k}$, you will have $$f\left(e^{10^k} \right)=10^k e^{-10^{k-2}}$$ which goes very fast to $0$ as shown in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 9.04837 \\
 2 & 36.7879 \\
 3 & 0.0453999 \\
 4 &3.72 \times 10^{-40} \\
 5 & 5.08 \times 10^{-430} \\
 6 & 1.14 \times 10^{-4337} \\
 7 & 3.56 \times 10^{-43423} \\
 8 & 3.29 \times 10^{-434287}\\
 9 & 1.51 \times 10^{-4342936} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$y:=\log(n) \rightarrow \exp(y) = n.$

$n^{1/100}= \exp(y/100)$.

$\dfrac{\log(n)}{n^{1/100}} =$

$\dfrac{y}{\exp(y/100)}=$

$\dfrac{100z}{\exp(z)}=: A(z)$, where

$z:= (y/100)$.

$\rightarrow :$

$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} A(z) = 0.$